# Hotmail option "Display as HTML" no longer works on my Galaxy SIII. Error message: "Connection failed"

Tags: email, html, hotmail

Recently, emails arriving via my Hotmail account have ceased to open when using the "Display as HTML" button option provided at the top right of the message. I just get an error message saying "Connection Failed", with the not too useful facility of being able to acknowledge this by pressing "OK"! This did not occur for the previous 7 months or so I have owned the phone. Is it a result of the latest update?

Comment: What was the update?

Comment: From memory, a firmware update about 10-12 days ago. Interestingly, I've received a request to update Samsung Push this morning. I wonder if this glitch has been more widespread and this includes a repair patch? Will check shortly. Thanks for responding.

Comment: No, doesn't fix it, unfortunately